# add minutes and print

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I need to code the following functionality:

1. User selects the day/frequency.
2. System shows list of available times/options.

For example: If the user selects 13th April and frequency 60 minutes the system should show the following options:

- 8:00 to 9:00
- 9:00 to 10:00
- 10:00 to 11:00
- 11:00 to 12:00
- and so on...

If the user selects frequency 30 minutes I should print out:
 - 8:00 to 8:30
 - 8:30 to 9:00
 - 9:00 to 9:30
 - 9:30 to 10:00
 - 10:00 to 10:30
 - and so on...

I would need help to come out with a good logic to build a function in order to do that. Inside this function I will check a calendar on a DB to see if the slot is available but I'm having some troubles to think on the best approach here. Do you guys have any good suggestion/example (especially to handle times in jquery)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Is it Javascript in frontend to create the UI for selecting these values? Is it PHP script that is validating if the spot is open? Explain what you have done so far and tell us what isn't working or what you have problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library, you can simply add minutes, seconds, ... to a given date.

1. [Parse](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the start moment from your user input.
2. In a loop [add your frequency](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to the last start moment to retrieve the next / end moment.
3. Process your times however you like.

Comment: this was the suggestion I was looking for. I've implemented Moment.js and I've used method like x.isAfter(), isSameOrBefore() to make the validations I needed. Thanks!